# downloading Lambda dependencies from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have been trying to work with lambda function to do some data analysis and then store the code in  snowflake.
since Lambda function is using Pandas, PyArrow and some other dependencies. Lambda funciton code exceeding limit 0f 250 Mb including layer as I had installed all these dependencies through lambda layers. So I was working on solution that I can keep dependencies in S3 bucket instead of layers. Now I was trying to download dependencies from S3 bucket that I uploaded.
Below adding simple code downloading pandas dependencies from S3 but looks like it is not working

```
import json
import boto3
import os
import subprocess
import zipfile
def download_code_from_s3(bucketName, file_path):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucketName) 
    bucket.download_file(file_path, os.path.join('/tmp/', file_path))
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  url_data = (r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oderofrancis/rona/main/Countries-Continents.csv')
  download_code_from_s3('truehelper', 'panda_layer.zip')
  #subprocess.run(['unzip', '/tmp/panda_layer.zip', '-d', '/tmp/'])
  print("File downloaded")
  from panda_layer import pandas as pd  
  df = pd.read_csv(url_data)
  print(df.head())


I am getting below error 

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "No module named 'panda_layer'",
  "errorType": "ModuleNotFoundError",
  "requestId": "fc8359ae-8b76-4049-b083-239662390b88",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 16, in lambda_handler\n    from panda_layer import pandas as pd\n"
  ]
}
```

It means it is not recognizing panda_layer dependency file I uploaded to S3.
Can someone help please ?

Comment: Is this your own solution or you're following any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of big dependencies, AWS introduced AWS Lambda container images. Those allow you to have 10GB of code + dependency installed.

You can see more details about setting it up in official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html)

Comment: I already figure it out but it is little complex